# Combining libwebsockets with normal sockets using poll() - SSL connection overhead?

Tags: ssl, single-threaded, libwebsockets

I have a single-threaded AIX server that polls multiple sockets and a message queue all using the poll() function (AIX has that neat feature of poll handling both, and it works well with ~1000 sockets). I'm wondering if it'd be a bad idea to add websockets support to the existing server - and whether it'd be better to add a separate server to handle websockets clients.

My interest in websockets is primarily to investigate the feasibility of re-implementing the C client in javascript within a browser.  Currently, the client uses winsock, and uses SRP (Secure Remote Password) to handle authentication and provide an encryption key for use with libdes to encrypt subsequent messages.

It might be nice to transition to websockets in the C client as well and ditch the 3des encryption logic in favor of SSL.  But I'm curious as to whether SSL authentication incurs enough overhead to be a problem in a single-threaded server.  Currently, my server passes on the SRP authentication handshake messages to a separate process via the backend message queue, so that any slowness in the authentication number crunches doesn't affect my server process.  Is the SSL handshake not a problem in a single-threaded server?

Comment: OpenSSL is able to work with non-blocking sockets; SSL_* functions will return error core WANT_READ or WANT_WRITE when they would block, so you can call poll/select and call again  the incomplete SSL-function when poll/select says data arrived (or free buffer available for WANT_WRITE)

Comment: I wasn't concerned about blocking I/O - poll() would be useless if sockets blocked.  But I was under the impression that strong-encryption authentication algorithms were very compute intensive, which I've taken to mean, they can take a significant amount of time.  So, I've never wanted that to occur in my single-threaded server process - which needs to service all sockets quickly.  But maybe that impression is out of date.  I guess if no part of the SSL authentication actually can take a significant amount of time, then it's not a problem to do SSL in a single threaded server.  Is that right?